# Is it Valid to Aggregate SHAP values to Sets of of Features?

Tags: python, shap

SHAP values seem to be additive and e.g. the overall feature importance plot simply adds the absolute SHAP values per feature and compares them.  This allows us to use SHAP for global importance aswell as local importance. We could also get feature importance for a particular subset of data records the same way.

By the same token, is it valid to get aggregate SHAP values for sets of variables? e.g. "Height", "Weight" and "Eye Colour" into "HumanDescription" or "Temperature", "Humidity" and "Air-Pressure" into "Weather"and rank them accordingly.

Theoretically, I can't see why not but would appreciate feedback on this in case of any gotchas.

Answer (score 5):

From Lundberg, package author: "The short answer is yes, you can add up SHAP values across the columns to get the importance of a whole group of features (just make sure you don't take the absolute value like we do when going across rows for global feature importance).

The long answer is that when Shapley values "fairly" allocate credit for interaction effects between features, they assume each feature in an interaction effect should get equal credit for the interaction. This means that for high order interaction terms you might get slightly different results when running Shapley values before (and summing) vs. after grouping features (since the new group just gets one chunk of the interaction pie so to speak, as opposed to multiple chunks when it was several features). These differences are typically small though so I wouldn't sweat it much since both ways are reasonable."

Comment: May I ask why we should not take the absolute SHAP values when summing across each data instance (the rows) when aggregating feature importance? For example, if height adds +5 to the base value and weight contributes -5 to the base value, is it really correct to say that overall, human description contributes 0 to the prediction rather than 10 by adding the absolute values?

Comment: I was wondering same thing and would interpret it as such.  SHAP is not just saying ' This group of variables is very impactful'.  The SHAP metric is directly interpretible as an effect on the target. 'Take away this group of variables and you will have zero difference' in your case. Having said that, the sum of absolutes measure is not without meaning.  You could report on it to show that there is a large impact although they in fact cancel on net.

Comment: @JohnCurry What if I am interested in the combined importance of features A and B if feature C were not included in the model? Do I row sum A, B, and (-1)*C? Then take mean absolute value?